How can I use a field of Foreign key (User Model) as the upload destination of FileField?
I have a Files model which has the User Model as Foreign key, I want to use the user's username as the name of the folder to which the files of the particular user will be uploaded. How can I achieve this?
I tried creating a getter function but that is not working.
Files Model:
class Files(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to='User')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_media_path())
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_media_path(self)->str:
        return self.user.username


You can change the file field as , file = models.FileField(upload_to=self.get_media_path)
and change the function accordingly . for example,return f'user_uploads/{self.user.username}/{filename}
